# Can I use a hashet or something else to find matches in lists?

Tags: c#, performance, list, hashset

I have 3 databases that need to be compared for existing values on a where clause.A souce database that is like a huge directory, a middle database that holds all the entries that belong to the final database, which holds entries that are assigned to people by using and ID.

I started out to build a list of items that match in one database based on all the items in form the source and used linq contains on the final database (exclude the middle one because I am not sure how to handle this yet)

My code looks like this so far

```
public static List<Models.FinalEntry> CrossCheck(List<Data.Models.SourceDatabase>  sourceEntities, int finalEntryFilterID)
{ 
   var _tels = sourceEntities.Select(x => x.Phone).ToList();

   FinalEntryDataContext db = new FinalEntryDataContext ();

   var finalEntryMatches = db.FinalEntries.Where(x => !x.IsArchived &
      x.FinalEntryMemberID == finalEntryFilterID &
      _tels.Contains(x.Telephone))
    .ToList();

    return finalEntryMatches ;
}
```

The source lists may contain tens of thousands of entries and the final might contains a subset of the source entries. Now I cannot use an ID from source to final because the source database can be wiped out, changed or even become a different one. That is why I match by telephone now, but I want to extend that to address and name later - which will make performance even worse!

I have been reading that using a `HashSet` will increase comparing speed. I just never used a hashset before and not sure how to implement it to increase searching/matching performance here?

Is using a hashet a good way? Or is there another way this can be done?

Comment: What ORM do you use? Is this LINQ to SQL, Entity Framework or something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code isn't *actually* going to be doing a linear search through the list.  It's not going to be doing any of the filtering in the application at all.  This code is going to be translated into SQL and then performed at the database, which will be responsible for optimizing the query itself.

Were you to be doing this filtering within your application then yes, you'd want to use a `HashSet` that could be *much* more efficiently searched, but you aren't, so it's not relevant.

What you have is fine, so long as the query provider succeeds in translating the query.

Comment: sourceEntities is a List<T>. That ain't happening on the server!

Comment: @KeithPayne Yes it is, because `db.FinalEntries` *is* an `IQueryable`.  It'll be mapped to an `IN` clause.  Of course, projecting that list to a list of phone numbers is happening in memory, but that's not what the question is asking about; it's asking about filtering the queryable by searching through that list

Comment: I first get the sourcedatabse a bit with a seperate query, then I use this extension to create a new list of a common Model I use (not shown in the code) So essentailly I go to the databse twice. Not ideal I know. but I understand it better this way and its all local anyway.

Comment: @ppumkin If at all possible, just don't materialize the first query into a list.  Simply *not* doing that will result in a single DB round trip, and most likely a radically more efficient query.  Always defer execution as much as you can.

Comment: @ppumkin: I do question the `&`'s in your code as opposed to `&&`.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I'm reasonably confident that they'll be mapped identically either way.  I'm not aware of SQL having non-short circuiting versions of those operators.  That said, getting in the habit of using the short circuiting AND is probably just a good habit, for cases of code actually executed in the application.

Comment: I didnt ask this but is there any way I can assign the SourceID(PK) in this query to the result set? Must I use a select at the end and assign the whole model back to mine? I was under the assumption that `&` in LInqToSQL tranaslated to SQL and ,, and the conditonal and `&&` runs on the server request. But possibly if I am testing a local variable , that applies. But all this is SQL, isnt it. So its jsut a habbit.

Comment: @ppumkin Not quite sure what you're asking, but if I understand you right, yes, you'll need to project out the whole model if you want to project it to a different type.

Comment: @Servy Thanks. I thought so. I am just thinking performance wise her because the searches already take 30~60 seconds without this cross-checking.. *sigh* I will back track and make sure I don't use ToList until the absolute final moment.

Comment: @ppumkin Don't materialize all of your queries before you need them, as I said earlier.  Only materialize your queries right when you need to use their results.  You also usually don't often need to materialize the query into a list *ever*.  In most cases you can just `foreach` over the items when you need them.

Comment: I just realised that one result set is form one database and I need to check against another database. So I have to materialize the source data before I can do the next query to the other database?

Comment: Woooo. That resulted in a `The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100.`

Comment: @ppumkin That pretty much makes this an entirely different question, however the best option is likely to upload the information in that list to a temp table in the other database, do a join, get the results, then clear the temp table.

Comment: Thanks. I realise because LINQ2SQL makes all these parameters its causing this error. If I create a query string and use `db.ExecuteQuery<>()` instead will the amount of where clauses (more than 10k) also hit a limitation?

Comment: @ppumkin That is not a L2S error, that's just a straight SQL error because the query provider is submitting a query with more than 2100 values in the `IN` clause.  If you have that much data it's just too much for your SQL query.  That's the whole point of that error message.

Comment: OK- Back to drawing board. Thanks for you help . Much appreciated.